# How can I put my bootstrap buttons in a vertical line going down in the centre of my webpage?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering how can I put my bootstrap buttons in a vertical line going down in the middle of my web page? I tried using      `vertical-align: top;`
 but it didn't work.

[My site code.](https://jsfiddle.net/jktsmruc/3/)

Here is the HTML to the buttons I want to go down one after the other in a vertical line in the middle of the web page.

```
<ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
   <li>
      <a href="devpage.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline rotateInUpLeft animated"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Web Development Portfolio</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="gfxdesign.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline rotateInUpLeft animated"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">GFX Design Portfolio</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline rotateInUpLeft animated"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">About Me</span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline rotateInUpLeft animated"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Contact Me</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

---

As a side note if anyone could also help me with this it would be much appreciated.

How can I adjust the width of how long the `<hr class="content-divider">` is but I need it to be responsive. I don't want the line to go past from where the buttons on each side end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul.intro-social-buttons li {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
```